# Grouping Rows in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm trying to figure out how to aggregate rows into batches (ie. a sliding / tumbling window) such that if we had a table like

```
  id   x    y   
 ---- ---- ---- 
   1   x1   y1  
   2   x2   y2  
   3   x3   y3  
   4   x4   y4  
   5   x5   y5
```

The result would be

```
  id   x    y                  Grouped x3                 
 ---- ---- ---- ----------------------------------------- 
   1   x1   y1   None                                     
   2   x2   y2   None                                     
   3   x3   y3   [[1, x1, y1], [2, x2, y2], [3, x3, y3]]  
   4   x4   y4   [[2, x2, y2], [3, x3, y3], [4, x4, y4]]  
   5   x5   y5   [[3, x3, y3], [4, x4, y4], [5, x5, y5]]
```

I currently have an aggregated column by using `concat_list` such that:

```
  id   x    y       List      
 ---- ---- ---- ------------- 
   1   x1   y1   [1, x1, y1]  
   2   x2   y2   [2, x2, y2]  
   3   x3   y3   [3, x3, y3]  
   4   x4   y4   [4, x4, y4]  
   5   x5   y5   [5, x5, y5]
```

I just don't know how to aggregate them across rows like the example above.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to perform this given your data is to use the [`groupby_rolling`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.groupby_rolling.html):

Let's start with your data and create the list of concatenated integers.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "x": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        "y": [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
    }
).with_column(pl.concat_list(pl.all()).alias('cat_list'))
df
```

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────────────┐
│ id  ┆ x   ┆ y   ┆ cat_list     │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---          │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ list[i64]    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 100 ┆ [1, 10, 100] │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 20  ┆ 200 ┆ [2, 20, 200] │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 30  ┆ 300 ┆ [3, 30, 300] │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 40  ┆ 400 ┆ [4, 40, 400] │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 50  ┆ 500 ┆ [5, 50, 500] │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────────────┘
```

From here, we can use a `groupby_rolling` and an index of `3i` against your `id`column.  In the `agg`, if no summary expression is used, then items in the group are automatically concatenated into a list -- in this case, a list of lists.

```py
group_result = (
    df
    .groupby_rolling(index_column='id', period='3i', closed='right')
    .agg(pl.col('cat_list').alias('result'))
)
group_result
```

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ result                              │
│ --- ┆ ---                                 │
│ i64 ┆ list[list[i64]]                     │
╞═════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [[1, 10, 100]]                      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ [[1, 10, 100], [2, 20, 200]]        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ [[1, 10, 100], [2, 20, 200], [3,... │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ [[2, 20, 200], [3, 30, 300], [4,... │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ [[3, 30, 300], [4, 40, 400], [5,... │
└─────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

From this point, you can simply add the column to your existing dataset.

```py
df = df.select(
    [
        pl.all(),
        group_result.get_column("result"),
    ]
)
df
```

```
shape: (5, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ x   ┆ y   ┆ cat_list     ┆ result                              │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---          ┆ ---                                 │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ list[i64]    ┆ list[list[i64]]                     │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 100 ┆ [1, 10, 100] ┆ [[1, 10, 100]]                      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 20  ┆ 200 ┆ [2, 20, 200] ┆ [[1, 10, 100], [2, 20, 200]]        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 30  ┆ 300 ┆ [3, 30, 300] ┆ [[1, 10, 100], [2, 20, 200], [3,... │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 40  ┆ 400 ┆ [4, 40, 400] ┆ [[2, 20, 200], [3, 30, 300], [4,... │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 50  ┆ 500 ┆ [5, 50, 500] ┆ [[3, 30, 300], [4, 40, 400], [5,... │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

If you need to adhere to a minimum window size, you can use a [`when/then/otherwise`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.when.html) and [`arr.lengths`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.expr.ExprListNameSpace.lengths.html#polars.internals.expr.ExprListNameSpace.lengths) to set values to None.

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.when(pl.col('result').arr.lengths() < 3)
    .then(None)
    .otherwise(pl.col('result'))
    .keep_name()
)
```

```
shape: (5, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ x   ┆ y   ┆ cat_list     ┆ result                              │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---          ┆ ---                                 │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ list[i64]    ┆ list[list[i64]]                     │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 100 ┆ [1, 10, 100] ┆ null                                │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 20  ┆ 200 ┆ [2, 20, 200] ┆ null                                │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 30  ┆ 300 ┆ [3, 30, 300] ┆ [[1, 10, 100], [2, 20, 200], [3,... │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 40  ┆ 400 ┆ [4, 40, 400] ┆ [[2, 20, 200], [3, 30, 300], [4,... │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 50  ┆ 500 ┆ [5, 50, 500] ┆ [[3, 30, 300], [4, 40, 400], [5,... │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```